# Using only numeric values in an object

Tags: r

testi have a table containing numeric values, including zeros.
I want to do a log-transformation on columns, yielding character strings "-Inf".
A shapiro.test consequently results in "NA" for any column containing characters after the log transformation.

However, is it possible to extract just the numeric values from that column and perform a shapiro.test afterwards? Maybe i can replace the "-Inf" with nothing?

Thank you for your help!

```
test <- log(x)
test
 [1] -Inf -7.562929 -7.424757 -6.284397 -6.637388 -8.141037 -5.371136 -7.093784 -6.489694 -6.529703
[11] -7.282913 -7.075025 -7.711110 -9.352510 -6.580074 -6.530339 -5.549224 -7.347854 -4.088114 -Inf (rest omitted)

str(test)
num [1:60] -7.32 -7.56 -7.42 -6.28 -6.64 ...

shapiro.test(test)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  test
W = NaN, p-value = NA
```

Comment: No, you mustn't simply remove the `-Inf`. Those are exact zeros in your original data. You could try using a different transformation, e.g., `sqrt(x)` or `log(x+1)`. However, I'm also a bit sceptical why you are using a test for normality.

Comment: I do spatial variogram model fitting, which assumes normality. I do sqrt, log, and square transformations to obtain normality. But you are right, i should have gone with log(x+1) from the start. I am still interested in the underlying question in relation to R ("How to extract a specific data type in mixed objects?").

Comment: As your values are small, you might want to consider using `log1p`

Comment: Thank you! I have just found a log transformation recommended by McCune "Analysis of Ecological Communities" 2002, page69. Will try both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a subset with all finite values using is.finite() function.

```
a = c(pi/0, 3,4,5,2,3)
a
[1] Inf  3  4  5  2  3
a = a[is.finite(a)]
a
[1] 3  4  5  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

In R `Inf` is a numeric value and not a string. It indicates the biggest possible double precision number. If you want to remove infinite values from a vector, you can try with the `is.finite` function, for instance:

```
    test[is.finite(test)]
```

Of course this will just remove the infinite, but it doesn't guarantee that what you are doing makes sense.