# r programming - check for every value in a vector if it is numeric

Tags: r

I am trying to create a logical vector in R, which will indicate for every value of a complete vector, if it is numeric or not.

I am trying to use the function `is.numeric` but it will only check if all the vector is numeric or not like that:

```
vec<-c(1,2,3,"lol")
t<-is.numeric(c[]) 
t
```

will produce `FALSE`

i looked [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html), but it will only tell how to check the entire vector and get a single value

i looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741065/using-only-numeric-values-in-an-object/25741842#25741842), but the issue is not finite vs infinite

i am trying to take a data set, with some values being numbers and other being a string that implies that there is no value, and find a minimum only in the numeric values. for that i try to create a logical vector that will say for every entry of the vector if it is numeric or not. this is important for me to create that vector and i am trying to avoid a complete loop and construction of that vector if possible.

Comment: Try `!is.na(as.numeric(vec))` for the index

Comment: A `vector` can be only of a single type. When you try to put together vectors of different kinds (as you did), the resulting vector will be of the "most expensive" type (`character` in your example). You can use `list` however, where every component of it can be of any type.

Comment: @PierreLafortune thanks you! i worked beautifully

Comment: Your example doesn't really make much sense if you don't show us what `c` is.

Comment: @RichardScriven c is a standard r function that concatenate objects to a vector...

Comment: Yes. I know. So try `c[]` and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use numeric coercion to our advantage. R will message us to be sure that we meant to change the strings to `NA`. In this case, it is exactly what we are looking for:

```
!is.na(as.numeric(vec))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `grepl` to get a logical vector.  We match that includes only numbers from start (`^`) to end (`$`).  I also included the possibility that there could be negative and floating point numbers.

```
grepl('^-?[0-9.]+$', vec)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

NOTE: There will be no warning messages.